# Database table doesn't exist, yet it does when trying to create it and afterwards

Tags: sqlite, qt

I'm trying to only initialize my sqlite database if the tables don't exist yet. If not, they should be created. Now the check always succeeds on the clean database (of course the table doesn't exist yet), but once I try to create it inside the `if`-block, sqlite complains that it does exist indeed. I can confirm that the table exists after that code ran, but I still receive that error message from the `qFatal` call.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QStringList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if(!db.open())
        qDebug() << "Couldn't open database file!";
    else
        qDebug() << "Opened database :memory:";

    qDebug() << "Existing tables:";
    QStringList::const_iterator it;
    for(it = db.tables().begin(); it != db.tables().end(); it++)
        qDebug() << it->toLocal8Bit().constData();
    qDebug() << "End";

    if(!db.tables().contains(QString("testtable")))
    {
        // The files table doesn't exist
        qDebug() << "Initializing DB";
        QString queryText = "CREATE TABLE testtable (id varchar(32) NOT NULL)";
        QSqlQuery query(queryText, db);
        if(!query.exec())
            qFatal("Couldn't initialize database: %s: %s", qPrintable(query.lastError().driverText()), qPrintable(query.lastError().databaseText()));
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Reference output:

```
Opened database :memory: 
Existing tables: 
End 
Initializing DB 
Couldn't initialize database: Unable to fetch row: table testtable already exists
```

I worked around the problem by using `IF NOT EXISTS` in the sql query, but that doesn't really clear things up.
(Qt 4.8 on OS X as well as Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missing something, but why you need any checks like that if you are using ":memory:" storage. Your database will be empty after process restart anyway.

Comment: The in-memory database was just for testing purposes so that I don't need to delete the database file after each test run. The final code should save data permanently.

Comment: Did I understood right, that then you working with real data on disk after application restart tables() returns empty set even if there are tables on disk file?

Comment: No, I always start out with an empty database and wonder why I get that error message when creating the 'testtable' - while said table has still been created despite the error when I check back via terminal in the database file.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this behaviour myself. If you look into the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/drivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp#n586), you'll see this line:

```
int openMode = (openReadOnlyOption ? SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY : (SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE));
```

Then, into [SQLite's source](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/3rdparty/sqlite/sqlite3.h#n2781):

```
** ^(<dt>[SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE] | [SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE]</dt>
** <dd>The database is opened for reading and writing, and is created if
** it does not already exist. This is the behavior that is always used for
** sqlite3_open() and sqlite3_open16().</dd>)^
```

I didn't follow it further than that, but I think it's safe to assume that Qt is passing this flag.

It seems to be a driver-specific behaviour, so perhaps that's why it's [not documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#open).